# How to get 'id' from table to modal to delete it with php

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm a super begginer in web developing. I need to take my table ID to a modal in order to delete the mySQL record. This is my code:

```html
<?php while($llenartabla = $getsibella->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><?=$llenartabla['id']?></th>
    <td><?=$llenartabla['date']?></td>
    <td><?=$llenartabla['location']?></td>
    <td><?=$llenartabla['city']?></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

And here is my code for the modal:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete the event?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="delete.php?id='I NEED THE ID HERE'" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know it's kind of an easy question, but I'm learning bootstrap and php haha. So any answers or comments are welcome :p

Comment: Some possible solution: listen `click` event of Delete `button` then rewrite target url then call to open modal or using `on show` event of modal to rewrite the url

Comment: And how do I do that? hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a newbie solution for you:

```
<?php while($llenartabla = $getsibella->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><?=$llenartabla['id']?></th>
    <td><?=$llenartabla['date']?></td>
    <td><?=$llenartabla['location']?></td>
    <td><?=$llenartabla['city']?></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?=$llenartabla['id']?>">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

just changed the following part: `data-target="#myModal<?=$llenartabla['id']?>"`

**As for modal:** again wrapped around the same loop with changed *id* of modal `id="myModal<?=$llenartabla['id']?>"` and your delete url modified `delete.php?id=$llenartabla['id']`

```
<?php while($llenartabla = $getsibella->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?=$llenartabla['id']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete the event?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="delete.php?id=$llenartabla['id']" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Now if you want the advance solution you need javascript.

Comment: Thanks! I wrapped the modal in the loop and add the <?=?> tag in the url and it worked! Just one more question. It is creating a modal each time it goes into the loop right? So, do I need JS in order to create just one modal in the whole page?

Comment: Yup, that's right. When you use JS you don't need to make this repeated stuff.

Comment: No problemo amigo :)